Why aren't the values i inserted showing up on the reports when i generate them?
When I try to generate the code as a whole I get Error:
Error Code 1050 table 'sakila.jrey_author' already exist 

When I try to generate the reports seperately it works, but it only generates the names of the columns in the table. (Disclaimer: these are not the original names of the tables, not comfortable with some of my personal information being out there)
create table sakila.jrey_author (
   author_id int,
   author_name VARCHAR(50),
   dateofbirth DATE,
   nationality VARCHAR(56) 
);

create table sakila.jrey_books(
   bookID int,
   title VARCHAR(50),
   IBSN INT,
   genreID INT,
   publicationyear INT,
   numAvailable INT,
   AuthorID INT,
   PublisherID INT
);

create table sakila.jrey_member(
   memberID INT,
   membername varchar(50),
   age INT,
   address varchar(25),
   phonenumber int,
   email varchar(61)
);

create table sakila.jrey_borrowedbooks(
   title varchar(60),
   bookID int,
   duedate DATE,
   transactionID int
);

create table sakila.jrey_transaction(
   transactionID int,
   transactiondate DATE,
   memberID int,
   bookID int,
   duedate DATE,
   status varchar(8)
);

insert into sakila.jrey_author (author_id, author_name, dateofbirth ,nationality) Values
('12','J.K. Rowlin','7/31/1965','British'),
('45','Stephen King','9/21/1947','American'),
('78','Jane Austen','12/16/1775','British'),
('32','George Orwell','6/25/1903','British'),
('23','Agatha Christie','9/15/1890','British'),
('56','Ernest Hemingway','7/21/1899','American');

insert into sakila.jrey_books values
('21',"Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone",'978-0439708180','1','1997','5','12'),
('78','The Shining','978-0307743657','2','1977','3','45'),
('34','Pride and Prejudice','978-0141439518','3','1813','2','78'),
('54','1984','978-0451524935','4','1949','8','32'),
('67','Murder on the Orient Express','978-0062073495','5','1934','4','23'),
('98','The Old Man and the Sea','978-0684801223','6','1952','7','56');

insert into sakila.jrey_member values
('34','John Moe','25','123 Main St, City','555-1234','john.doe@yahoo.com'),
('45','Jane Smith','30','456 Oak St, Town','555-5678','jane.smith@email.com'),
('56','Bob Johnson','40','789 Elm St, Village','555-9101','bob.johnson@yahoo.com'),
('67','Sarah Williams','28','321 Pine St, Hamlet','555-1212','sarah.williams@gmail.com'),
('78','Michael Brown','35','654 Cedar St, County','555-3434','michael.brown@email.com'),
('98','Emily Davis','42','987 Maple St, Village','555-5656','emily.davis@gmail.com');

insert into sakila.jrey_borrowedbooks values
("Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone",'21','4/3/2024','12'),
('The Shining','78','4/5/2024','67'),
('Pride and Prejudice','34','4/6/2024','56'),
('1984','54','4/7/2024','23'),
('Murder on the Orient Express','67','4/8/2024','78'),
('The Old Man and the Sea','98','4/9/2024','45');

insert into sakila.jrey_transaction values
('12','3/20/2024','45','21','4/3/2024','Borrowed'),
('67','3/21/2024','34','78','4/5/2024','Returned'),
('56','3/22/2024','98','34','4/6/2024','Borrowed'),
('23','3/23/2024','21','54','4/7/2024','Borrowed'),
('78','3/24/2024','12','67','4/8/2024','Returned'),
('45','3/25/2024','67','98','4/9/2024','Borrowed');

SELECT *
FROM sakila.jrey_author;

SELECT *
FROM sakila.jrey_books;

SELECT *
FROM sakila.jrey_member;

SELECT *
FROM sakila.jrey_borrowedbooks;

SELECT *
FROM sakila.jrey_transaction;

I tried to see if I inserted the data incorrectly so I changed 'insert into table name values' by adding the full names of the columns before values, but it gave me the same results.

I'm unclear on what you mean when you refer to the reports, but I'd be surprised if your inserts "work". Your books table has more columns (8) than the values you are inserting (7). Also Your IBSN column is defined as int, but has string values (e.g. '978-0307743657'), likewise your phonenumber column in jrey_member.

Use CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS to prevent the "table already exists" error.

But if the tables already exist, they might have different schemas, so the INSERT queries won't work.

MySQL expects dates to be formatted in YYYY-MM-DD format, not MM/DD/YYYY. If you want to use some other format you need to use STR_TO_DATE() to parse it.

BTW, the correct abbreviation is ISBN (International Standard Book Number), not IBSN.

Sakila is a sample database in MySQL developed by Mike Hillyer.
Check MySQL Documentation for details.
You are getting error:
Error Code 1050 table 'sakila.jrey_author' already exist 

because you're not deleteing the existing Sakila DB tables.
So, First delete table & then create
Use query at top:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sakila.jrey_author;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sakila.jrey_books;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sakila.jrey_member;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS jrey_borrowedbooks;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sakila.jrey_transaction;

Next correct your data. I found there are lots of data issue as follows:

Correct Date format from MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD (standard format).
Check Columndata type and it's inserting values as follows:

sakila.jrey_books table's column PublisherID INT data not avalible in insert query (check image)

Ok, I have correct few thing and it's working properly.
This is full code:
USE sakila;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sakila.jrey_author;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sakila.jrey_books;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sakila.jrey_member;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS jrey_borrowedbooks;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sakila.jrey_transaction;

create table sakila.jrey_author (
   author_id int,
   author_name VARCHAR(50),
   dateofbirth DATE,
   nationality VARCHAR(56) 
);

create table sakila.jrey_books(
   bookID int,
   title VARCHAR(50),
   IBSN VARCHAR(20),
   genreID INT,
   publicationyear INT,
   numAvailable INT,
   AuthorID INT
   -- PublisherID INT
);

create table sakila.jrey_member(
   memberID INT,
   membername varchar(50),
   age INT,
   address varchar(25),
   phonenumber varchar(20),
   email varchar(61)
);

create table sakila.jrey_borrowedbooks(
   title varchar(60),
   bookID int,
   duedate DATE,
   transactionID int
);

create table sakila.jrey_transaction(
   transactionID int,
   transactiondate DATE,
   memberID int,
   bookID int,
   duedate DATE,
   status varchar(8)
);

insert into sakila.jrey_author (author_id, author_name, dateofbirth ,nationality) Values
   (12,'J.K. Rowlin','1965-07-31','British'),
   (45,'Stephen King','1947-09-21','American'),
   (78,'Jane Austen','1775-12-16','British'),
   (32,'George Orwell','1903-06-25','British'),
   (23,'Agatha Christie','1890-09-15','British'),
   (56,'Ernest Hemingway','1899-07-21','American');

insert into sakila.jrey_books values
   (21,"Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone",'978-0439708180',1,1997,5,12),
   (78,'The Shining','978-0307743657',2,1977,3,45),
   (34,'Pride and Prejudice','978-0141439518',3,1813,2,78),
   (54,'1984','978-0451524935',4,1949,8,32),
   (67,'Murder on the Orient Express','978-0062073495',5,1934,4,23),
   (98,'The Old Man and the Sea','978-0684801223',6,1952,7,56);

insert into sakila.jrey_member values
   (34,'John Moe',25,'123 Main St, City','555-1234','john.doe@yahoo.com'),
   (45,'Jane Smith',30,'456 Oak St, Town','555-5678','jane.smith@email.com'),
   (56,'Bob Johnson',40,'789 Elm St, Village','555-9101','bob.johnson@yahoo.com'),
   (67,'Sarah Williams',28,'321 Pine St, Hamlet','555-1212','sarah.williams@gmail.com'),
   (78,'Michael Brown',35,'654 Cedar St, County','555-3434','michael.brown@email.com'),
   (98,'Emily Davis',42,'987 Maple St, Village','555-5656','emily.davis@gmail.com');

insert into sakila.jrey_borrowedbooks values
   ("Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone",21,'2024-04-03',12),
   ('The Shining',78,'2024-04-05',67),
   ('Pride and Prejudice',34,'2024-04-06',56),
   ('1984',54,'2024-04-07',23),
   ('Murder on the Orient Express',67,'2024-04-08',78),
   ('The Old Man and the Sea',98,'2024-04-09',45);

insert into sakila.jrey_transaction values
   (12,'2024-03-20',45,21,'2024-04-03','Borrowed'),
   (67,'2024-03-21',34,78,'2024-04-05','Returned'),
   (56,'2024-03-22',98,34,'2024-04-06','Borrowed'),
   (23,'2024-03-23',21,54,'2024-04-07','Borrowed'),
   (78,'2024-03-24',12,67,'2024-04-08','Returned'),
   (45,'2024-03-25',67,98,'2024-04-09','Borrowed');

SELECT *
FROM sakila.jrey_author;

SELECT *
FROM sakila.jrey_books;

SELECT *
FROM sakila.jrey_member;

SELECT *
FROM sakila.jrey_borrowedbooks;

SELECT *
FROM sakila.jrey_transaction;


Thank You !!!
